# I couldn't match the pattern using str_replace_all

Tags: r, str-replace

I have a regex problem. One of my data table column is something like this:

`d:Bacteria(0.8400),p:Actinobacteria(0.1176),c:Actinobacteria(0.01...`

and I want to remove all parentheses including float inside. I wrote the code below and it didn't work. Where am I wrong?

```
read_tsv("raw_data/taxonomy.txt", col_names = FALSE)%>%
  setNames(c("OTU","Taxonomy","label","domain")) %>%
  rename_all(tolower)%>%
  select(otu, taxonomy)%>%
  mutate(otu = tolower(otu),
         taxonomy = str_replace_all(taxonomy, "\\(\\d+\\)", ""))
```

Comment: It doesn't match because the numbers have a decimal point which is not matched by \d

Comment: Regex should be `"\\(.+?\\)"`, the `?` is necessary for lazy evaluation.

Comment: It can be helpful to experiment with regular expressions in a more interactive environment, such as [this regex playground](https://regex101.com/). Put in your sample data, and then play around with expressions until you get a match. There is a lot of help for the different kinds of matching device available.